# HangFire Recurring Jobs Fail on server with Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException or No parameterless exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I've just started using HangFire. The jobs seem to work fine when I run it locally from IIS Express, but when I run it on my dev server I get errors that no parameterless constructor defined. I was using Simple Injector earlier but now I've moved to Autofac.

```
 public class Startup
{

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        ConfigureIoc(app);
        ConfigureRoutes();
        ConfigureHangfire(app);
        ScheduleXeroMonitor();
    }

    public void ConfigureHangfire(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var authList = new List<IDashboardAuthorizationFilter>
        {
            new ClaimsBasedAuthorizationFilter("role", "admin")
        };
        var options = new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = authList,
            AppPath = "/Manage"

        };

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options);
        app.UseHangfireServer();
    }

    public void ConfigureRoutes()
    {
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    public void ConfigureIoc(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = DependencyRegistrar.RegisterClasses();
        var container = builder.Build();
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacMvc();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
        });
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
        });


        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;
    }

    public void ScheduleXeroMonitor()
    {            
        var backGroundWorker = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IXeroBackGroundWorker>();            
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("XeroPolling", () => backGroundWorker.PollJobs(), Cron.Minutely); //change the Cron to every 5 minutes    

        var emailWorker = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IEmailService>();
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("EmailPolling", () => emailWorker.SendQueuedEmails(), Cron.Minutely);//"*/10 * * * *"
    }
}
```

Here's the code where I register my dependencies.

```
public class DependencyRegistrar
{
    public static ContainerBuilder RegisterClasses()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<XeroSyncRestClient>().As<IXeroSyncRestClient>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<XeroBackGroundWorker>().As<IXeroBackGroundWorker>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<EmailService>().As<IEmailService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());            
        return builder;
    }

}
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've also posted this on Hangfire discussion forum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already added `AutoFac` in `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(container);` You just simple let hangfire and Autofac resolve dependencies for you.

```
public void ScheduleXeroMonitor()
{            
    //var backGroundWorker = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IXeroBackGroundWorker>();  --> let hangfire and autofac do this for you          
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IXeroBackGroundWorker>("XeroPolling", backGroundWorker => backGroundWorker.PollJobs(), Cron.Minutely); //change the Cron to every 5 minutes    

    //var emailWorker = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IEmailService>();--> let hangfire and autofac do this for you          
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IEmailService>("EmailPolling", emailWorker => emailWorker.SendQueuedEmails(), Cron.Minutely);//"*/10 * * * *"
}
```